# BigQuery query taking a long time

Tags: google-bigquery

a simple count query on one of my tables takes a long time to complete (~18 secs), this table has around half a million rows, and making the same query in a bigger table (around 3 mil) takes less than 3 secs. The schema is exactly the same and the query is a simple SELECT count(*) FROM [dataset.table]

Any ideas why this is happening and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: How much data is each query processing?

Comment: Can you provide a job id for the query that took 18 seconds?

Comment: @JenTong : According to the UI, a count processes 0B. The table itself has 404 MB according to the same UI

Comment: @JordanTigani : I can provide it, it happens each time i do the query, should I just post the id here?

Comment: Yes, please post it, it will let one of the BigQuery engineers look at the query statistics to try to figure out what is going wrong. COUNT(*) over a small table should not take that long.

Comment: Here's the job id for one of the queries sertech-arq:job_ZlK-1Gd22EbbwWFA61x1kEhLoc8

Apparently every query made against that table is taking that long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue with your table is that it was created in a lot of small chunks; this takes more work to query, since we spend a lot of time on filesystem operations (listing files and opening them).

Even so, a table the size of yours should not be so slow; BigQuery is currently experiencing high filesystem load that is causing high variability in latency. We're actively working on resolving this one. So that is the first problem.

The second problem is that we probably should do a better job of compacting the table. I've filed an internal bug that we should tweak our heuristics to be a bit more aggressive in compaction.

As a workaround, you can compact the table manually by copying the table in place. In other words, run a `SELECT * from ...` and writing the output to the same table, using `writeDisposition:WRITE_TRUNCATE`, `destinationTable:<your table>`  and `allowLargeResults:true` and `flattenSchema:false`.

Again, this last step shouldn't be needed, but for now it should improve your situation.

Comment: One caveat on self-compacting via a "select *" query: you can only do this if no data is loaded between the start of the query and query completion. The view of data a query runs over is determined at the start of the operation, and a WRITE_TRUNCATE will occur at the point in time that the job ends successfully. If you are streaming data to the table or running load jobs, then you risk data loss via this technique.

Comment: My table was created without any data, and then all of it was (is being) streamed into it. Will I encounter this problem frequently if I do this? Would loading data into it in bigger chunks instead of streaming prevent this from happening?

I can easily stop streaming, self-compact, and then resume streaming. But how often would I need to do this?